# gcc -m32 not working on Windows hosted agents

Tags: windows, gcc, azure-pipelines

I’ve created a simple Azure DevOps pipeline on hosted agent with vs2017-win2016 image:

1. Prepare C file [PowerShell task]:

   ```
   New-Item "test.c" -ItemType File -Value "int Foo() { return 123; }"
   ```
2. Build DLL [CommandLine task]:

   ```
   gcc -v -c test.c -m32
   gcc -v -shared -o test.dll test.o -m32
   ```

But the second step failed with:

_

```
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -luser32
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lkernel32
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -liconv
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmoldname
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt_

**collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status**
```

I suppose something not set up properly with MinGW on hosted agents which leads to `-m32` option can’t be used and thus it’s impossible to build 32-bit DLL with gcc.

There are number of questions on the web on the similar problem, but I can't understand from them what I exactly need to do on 64-bit Windows to make gcc work with -m32 switch and build 32-bit DLL.

Sine I use Azure DevOps, it would be great to install required software via `choco` or something like that, i.e. via automating tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Bright Ran-MSFT** said there is no MinGW32 installed on hosted agents. Self-hosted agents is not an option for me.

After hours of searching and trying different solutions I finally found the solution. There is a project called [winlibs](https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_mingw) which contains all compilers including i686 which can build 32-bit DLL on 64-bit Windows.

So I ended up with this PowerShell script within my pipeline:

```
Write-Host "Downloading winlibs..."
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_mingw/releases/download/11.1.0-12.0.0-9.0.0-r1/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-11.1.0-mingw-w64-9.0.0-r1.zip" -OutFile "winlibs.zip"
Write-Host "Downloaded."

Write-Host "Extracting winlibs..."
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'winlibs.zip' -DestinationPath "winlibs"
Write-Host "Extracted."

Write-Host "Building DLL..."
$gccPath = Get-ChildItem -Path "winlibs" -File -Filter "i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe" -Recurse

& $gccPath.FullName -c test.c -m32
& $gccPath.FullName -shared -o test.dll test.o -m32
Write-Host "Built."
```

Comment: Hi @Maxim, Glad that you have found a solution, and thanks for sharing the solution. I recommend that you can mark this answer as the solution of this topic. This may be very helpful to other people who are looking for a solution for the similar issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Marked the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the Microsoft-hosted Windows agents, the pre-installed MinGW is **`Mingw-w64 8.1.0`**, no **`MinGW32`** installed.

To install **`MinGW32`** on the Microsoft-hosted agents, you need to execute some related command lines in the pipeline. I searched and tried, but did not find any available command can be used to install MinGW on Windows.

As a workaround, maybe you can try manually install **`MinGW32`** on your local Windows machine and then add a self-hosted agent on the local Windows machine to run the pipeline.

You can reference the following article to install MinGW on Windows:

- [Installing the 32-bit and 64-bit C (gcc) and C++ (g++) Compilers on Windows](https://azrael.digipen.edu/%7Emmead/www/public/mingw/)

Comment: So `-m32` option works only if MinGW32 installed? As far as I know it's deprecated and only MinGW64 is maintaining which should build binaries both 32- and 64-bit.

Comment: Also by the logs there are pathes like `C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/…/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/…/…/…/…/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin` so it seems mingw32 is present, but don't work for some reason.